# ctypes __del__ of ctypes.Structure subclass not invoked for pointers to structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

The C library I'm wrapping requires allocating and destroying the memory of the structure inside of C functions, and always passes pointers, not structures.

I have a subclass of `ctypes.Structure` with a `__del__` method. This method is not invoked when calling `del` on an instance that is a pointer to the structure returned from a function in C (`Foo_init`). Interestingly, it is invoked when calling `del` if that instance is not a pointer, but the actual value, returned from a different C function (`Foo_init_value`).

How can I get the `__del__` method to invoke for pointers to structures that were returned from a function in C?

In Python:

```
import ctypes
import gc
libfoo = ctypes.CDLL("libfoo.so")

class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', ctypes.c_int),
        ('b', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)),
    ]
    def __del__(self):
        print('deleting')
        libfoo.Foo_destroy(self)

# Get a pointer to Foo
libfoo.Foo_init.restype = ctypes.POINTER(Foo)
libfoo.Foo_init.argtypes = None

# Get actual Foo, not pointer
libfoo.Foo_init_value.restype = Foo
libfoo.Foo_init_value.argtypes = None

libfoo.Foo_destroy.restype = ctypes.c_int
libfoo.Foo_destroy.argtypes = [ctypes.POINTER(Foo)]

# Get a pointer to Foo
foo = libfoo.Foo_init()
# Nothing is printed here:
del foo
# Nothing is printed here
gc.collect()
# Nothing is printed here
[f for f in gc.get_objects() if isinstance(f, Foo)]

# Get an actual Foo, not pointer
foo = libfoo.Foo_init_value()
# This works, prints 'deleting', but crashes with freeing an invalid pointer
# presumably because __del__ is passing the struct, not pointer to struct
del foo
```

Here is my trivial C library:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Foo {
    int a;
    char *b;
} Foo;

/* Allocate and return pointer to Foo */
/* __del__ does not work for this one */
Foo *Foo_init(void)
{
    Foo *foo = (Foo *) malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    foo->a = 0;
    foo->b = NULL;
    return foo;
}

/* Allocate and return value of Foo, not a pointer*/
/* __del__ works on this */
Foo Foo_init_value(void)
{
    Foo *foo = Foo_init();
    return *foo;
}

int *Foo_destroy(Foo *foo)
{
    if (foo->b) {
         free(foo->b);
         foo->b = NULL;
    }
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile:

```
gcc -c -Wall -Werror -fpic foo.c
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

Comment: What's settled and what can be changed? Regarding the *.dll*, can the functions signatures be altered?

Comment: @CristiFati the function signatures cannot be altered; they are from a proprietary/legacy API provided by a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

This works but I assume there is a much better way of doing it:

```
Foop = ctypes.POINTER(Foo)

def foo_del(self):
    print('deleting')
    libfoo.Foo_destroy(self)

Foop.__del__ = foo_del

foo = libfoo.Foo_init()
# prints 'deleting'
del foo
```